# Mutating y axis in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I would like to ask how I can possibly mutate the y axis in this example. I do not want to do any sort of transformation, I simply would like to have even breaks, but defined by me (in my own real example I have lots in the range of 0:300 and one tall bar in one category, so I would like to boost the lower bars)

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(c(rnorm(20,10,2),rnorm(30,50,5),rnorm(25,5,0.5)),
                   c(rnorm(75,60,20)),
                   c(rep("A",20),rep("B",30),rep("C",25)))
colnames(df) <- c("bags","dist","source")

df %>%
        mutate(bin = cut(dist, breaks = c(min(dist),18, 30,40, 50, max(dist)))) %>%  # specify ranges
        group_by(source, bin) %>%
        summarise(sum_number = sum(bags)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        ggplot(aes(bin, sum_number, fill=source))+
        geom_col()+
        xlab("Km")+
        ylab("Number of bags")+
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("#a6611a","#dfc27d","#bababa"),
                          labels = unique(df$source),
                          name = "")+
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1200), breaks = 
                           c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,500,1000), 
                           labels = c("0", "50", "100","150", `"200","250","300", "500","1,000")) +`
        theme_minimal()
```

The code above is only applying chosen ticks but is not rescaling the y-axis which is what I need.

[image]

Comment: Would scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1200),
                     breaks = c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,500,1000),
                     labels = c("0", "50", "100","150", "200", "250","300", "500","1,000"))  work?

Comment: Note that breaking scales is disingenuous - it can lead to mis-interpretation of data. You may be better off using a transformed (e.g. `log10`) scale (I know you didn't want to do this, but it is the correct thing to do usually).

Comment: @HarroCyranka I added it, and the results can be seen. What I need is to rescale the y axis, any idea how to do it?